# React - useState not setting initial value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm refactoring to use Hooks and I've hit a very confusing wall

I have a basic functional component like so:

```js
export const MakeComponent = props => {
  const { path, value, info, update } = props;

  const [val, setVal] = useState(value);
  console.log(value, val); // abc undefined

 return (...)
}
```

The log returns `abc undefined` - i.e. `value` in props is definitely defined, but the first argument returned from `useState(value)` is `undefined`

Just to test that hooks were working at all, I tried `useState("abc")` and that logs `abc` as expected.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong - any ideas?

React version: `16.8.6`

EDIT here is the parent component - nothing fancy going on here as far as I can see!

```
<MakeComponent
  path={key}
  value={item[key]}
  info={value}
  update={updateDiffs}
/>
```

Comment: How are you calling `MakeComponent`?

Comment: useState hook is also asynchronous, and will not immediately reflect and update but will trigger a re-render as one of issue.

Comment: @Dupocas both as a function `MakeComponent({...})` and as jsx `<MakeComponent {...props} />` - no difference :(

Comment: Calling a component like a function is invalid. But I meant `{...props}` how it looks like? Could you post code for the parent component?

Comment: make sure that 'value' received form props is undefined or not. if possible do share some good code snippet

Comment: @PalaniichukDmytro When I try `useState("abc")` it logs immediately before rendering

Comment: @ShoyebMemon `value` is definitely defined - it logs correctly

Comment: Where this `item` comes from?

Comment: @devserkan from the parent component - it's definitely defined and consequently `value` is definitely defined in `props` - this is why I'm so confused :(

Comment: Ok parent but as a result of async operation? If it is not too complicated you can create a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/).

Comment: @devserkan it's actually too complicated! But I have a guard before rendering: `!!item && <MakeComponent {...props} />` so MakeComponent isn't called unless `item` is defined

Comment: I think the `value` prop is initially `undefined` and updated later on, so the state is initialized as `undefined`

Comment: I'm thinking @abidibo and @devserkan are correct and I've been careless somewhere and allowed the component to be called before `item` is defined - I'll rewrite it from scratch and update this question if I can figure out what is going on

Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: @rubie IMO, you can very well write your component when a prop is not yet initialized, it can be a response of and async process. You need to use effects. I have written a response including that below.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

As it is alluded to in the comments, `useState(initialState)` (or whatever you call it) will only use `initialState` on the first render.

> The value you want the state to be initially. It can be a value of any type, but there is a special behavior for functions. *This argument is ignored after the initial render.*

([React Docs](https://react.dev/reference/react/useState), emphasis mine)

After this, on re-renders the useState function does not change the state based on new changes to the props passed in.

To make changes reflected everytime `value` changes, register an effect on the input prop like so

```js
export const MakeComponent = props => {
  const { path, value, info, update } = props;

  const [val, setVal] = useState(value);
  useEffect(() => { setVal(value)}, [value] )

 return (...)
}
```

---

Note that just setting state based on the props changing is a bit of an [anti-pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern), as [MonsterBucket](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19344671/monsterbasket) notices you could just rely directly on the props changing to trigger a re-render:

```js
export const MakeComponent = props => {
  const { path, value, info, update } = props;

  const [val, setVal] = useState(value);
  if (val !== value) { // don't update unnecessarily
    setVal(value);
  }

 return (...)
}
```

And instead reserve useEffect for *side* effects, mostly those outside of the React render cycle.

To see examples of these, have a look as these [ReactJs docs - You might not need an effect](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect), which covers lots of other examples.

Comment: first answer makes an infinite loop and the second answer causes the "Too many re-renders" Error

Comment: @Ali, I'll need to see more of your code to help, so feel free to [ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and link it here

Answer (score 9):

Here you have to add `useEffect` if you want to update the state on props change, which will listen to prop change & will update the state value accordingly

here is the updated snippet

```
export const MakeComponent = props => {
     const { path, value, info, update } = props;
        
     const [val, setVal] = useState(value);
     useEffect(() => { setVal(value)}, [value] )
     return (<div>{val}</div>)
}
```

Attching sandbox link

https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-agnesi-ohkq7?file=/src/MakeComponent.js

Comment: this gave me a return of `{ object Object }` and debugger shows `val = {value: undefined}`

Comment: @idanicoleherbert Added the codesandbox demo, you can compare your changes with that & update

Answer (score 8):

By the time you pass the prop `value` to `useState` the value of it can be yet to set. `value` itself might have been `undefined` yet.

Also `setState` is not truly *sync* so if the `useState` uses same mechanism as `setState` your state `val` might not be set to `value` yet as the initial value.

In such cases, using props as the initial values to states, you should use a side *effect* with no dependency. Once the first render achieved the effect will run and set your state with prop. You can let the initial value of the component be undefined passing nothing with no problems.

```
export const MakeComponent = props => {
  const { path, value, info, update } = props;

  const [val, setVal] = useState();

  // get initial state after initial render
  useEffect(() => {
    setVal(value)
  }, [])
  console.log(value, val); // abc undefined then will log abc abc

 return (...)
}
```

Just keep in mind that props in React are meant to be read-only, state is for read and write. But it is perfectly fine, and no not an anti pattern, if you use a prop just as an initial value for a state and use the state you have set with the prop after that instead of the prop. That is for consistency since you might have two different values at a time from a prop and a state in circumstances.

Your case might need to care for the value of the prop at an arbitrary time depending on you needs as stressed in one of the above answers. You question does not state that. Still, if so, you can add the prop to the dependency array of the effect that sets the state with that prop, and yes write separate effects for other props you want the same, well, effect.

If you don't need writing for that data you do not need that pattern at all, just use prop and it will be up to date and you will have consistency. But you apparently do so I hope the pattern I suggest above works for you as it does for me.